# flattening nested array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

```
function array_flatten($array,$return) {
    for($x = 0; $x <= count($array); $x++) {
        if(is_array($array[$x])) {
            $return = array_flatten($array[$x], $return); //4th line
        }
        else {
            if(isset($array[$x])) {
                 $return[] = $array[$x];
            }
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

$res = array_flatten($myarray, array());
```

I used the above function to flatten my nested, but am still struggling to figure out why do the author passed the function back to $return on line 4.
and if I were to change $return on line 4 to something else, the function breaks. Can anyone explain..

Comment: That's a recursive call. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Can you tell the array input and what the expected output you want?

Comment: Inputting a multidimentional array will result in 1 dimensional array